# React-native Atempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.double.doublevalue()' on a null object reference (2019)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-reanimated

Seems to be a problem with react-native-reanimated

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a problem with react-native-reanimated 1.5.0 which was released a few hours ago. Downgrading to 1.4.0 solved it

```
"react-native-reanimated": "1.4.0"
```

Comment: This is great job !

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case it was that a call to `ToastAndroid.show(text, timeout)` was missing the `timeout` parameter.

For these kinds of scenarios I recommend migrating to react native with typescript.